# Datastream does not read from Kafka using flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am running Kafka on my local and publishing data to it using

`kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic som_test_event`

and trying to read and print it using the code below. But it is not working. What am I missing?

```java
public class Flink {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment executionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        executionEnvironment.enableCheckpointing(5000L);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "myGroup");
        properties.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");

        FlinkKafkaConsumer010<DeliveryEventSerializationV1> consumer =
                new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<>("som_test_event", new InputMessageDeserializationSchema(), properties);

        DataStream<DeliveryEventSerializationV1> dataStream = executionEnvironment
                .addSource(consumer)
                .rebalance()


        dataStream.addSink(
                StreamingFileSink
                        .forBulkFormat(new Path("/Users/xyz/FlinkOut"),
                                ParquetAvroWriters.forReflectRecord(DeliveryEventSerializationV1.class))
                        .withRollingPolicy(OnCheckpointRollingPolicy.build())
                        .build());

        dataStream.print();

        executionEnvironment.execute();
    }

}
```

Comment: try adding properties.setProperty("group.id", "myGroup"); and properties.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");

Comment: Still does not work

Comment: There seems to be some code missing. Where is `datastream` declared and initialized?